# How do I set a background for each item of ListView in Android without click them?

Tags: java, android

I want to change each item in list view have a different color background without click them, without use textview.

I try to this, but it don't work,

Main.Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listColor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listColor = findViewById(R.id.ListColor);
        ArrayList<String> color = new ArrayList<String>();
        color.add("#aa0000");
        color.add("#aaaa00");
        color.add("#00aa00");

        ArrayAdapter<String> colorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
               color
        );
       listColor.setAdapter(colorAdapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml;

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ListColor"

            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try adapter like below

    ArrayAdapter<String> colorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                   color
            ) {
    
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color.get(position))
                return view;
            }
        };
    listColor.setAdapter(colorAdapter);
```